# SQL stored procedure compile error: wrong number or types of arguments in call

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures

I have created this stored procedure. However I get this error

> ORA-06550:line 14 column 3: PLS-00306:
>   wrong number or types of arguments in
>   call to 'CHALLENGEUPDATE' when the
>   values passed are    CUSTID
>   :='400800500' ;   POLICYNAME :=
>   'POLICY';   CHALLENGEID :=
>   'CHALLENGEID1';   PINPOSITIONS :=
>   'PINPOS';

The code is:

```
create or replace
procedure ChallengeUpdate  
(
   CustID        IN   SEC_CHALLENGE.CUSTOMERID%TYPE,
   PolicyName      IN   SEC_CHALLENGE.POLICY_NAME%TYPE,
   ChallengeId       IN   SEC_CHALLENGE.CHALLENGE_ID%TYPE,
   PinPositions       IN   SEC_CHALLENGE.PINPOSITIONS%TYPE,
   o_result   OUT  INTEGER,
   o_code OUT INTEGER,
   o_c OUT INTEGER
)
as
        c integer;
    begin
        select count(*) into c  from SEC_CHALLENGE xyz where xyz.CUSTOMERID=CustID and 
            xyz.POLICY_NAME=PolicyName;

        if c = 0 then
           INSERT INTO SEC_CHALLENGE(CUSTOMERID,CHALLENGE_ID,PINPOSITIONS,POLICY_NAME)
            VALUES (CustID,ChallengeId, PinPositions, PolicyName);

        else
            UPDATE RBSSEC_CHALLENGE 
            SET CHALLENGE_ID=ChallengeId, PINPOSITIONS=PinPositions
            WHERE CUSTOMERID=CustID and POLICY_NAME = PolicyName;
        end if;
        commit;
        o_result:=0;
        o_c:=c;
        exception when others then 
        o_result:=-1; 
        o_c:=c;
        rollback;
        o_code :=SQLCODE;
    end ChallengeUpdate;
```

The SEC_CHALLENGE table is this

```
CREATE TABLE "MUJEEB"."RBSSEC_CHALLENGE"
  (
    "CUSTOMERID"   VARCHAR2(9 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "CHALLENGE_ID" VARCHAR2(50 BYTE),
    "PINPOSITIONS" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "POLICY_NAME"  VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    CONSTRAINT "RBSSEC_CHALLENGE1_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("CHALLENGE_ID")
)
```

here is how I am running it:

```
DECLARE CUSTID VARCHAR2(9); 
        POLICYNAME VARCHAR2(50); 
        CHALLENGEID VARCHAR2(50); 
        PINPOSITIONS VARCHAR2(20); 
        O_RESULT NUMBER; 
        O_CODE NUMBER; 
BEGIN   CUSTID :='400800500' ; 
        POLICYNAME := 'POLICY'; 
        CHALLENGEID := 'CHALLENGEID1'; 
        PINPOSITIONS := 'PINPOS'; 
        CHALLENGEUPDATE( CUSTID => CUSTID, POLICYNAME => POLICYNAME, CHALLENGEID => CHALLENGEID, PINPOSITIONS => PINPOSITIONS, O_RESULT => O_RESULT, O_CODE => O_CODE ); 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('O_RESULT = ' || O_RESULT); 
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('O_CODE = ' || O_CODE); 
END;
```

Comment: Please can you find the issue here

Comment: Please show how you called it exactly.  Did you pass variables for the OUT parameters?

Comment: call ChallengeUpdate(?,?,?,?) this is wrong, you need to pass all the parameters, even the out parameters ,you are missing 3 "?"

Answer (score 3):

If you use output parameters, marked with the "out" keyword, you must pass a variable for that parameter. Output params are not optional. From the error, I gather that you have not done so.

Comment: Here is how i am running it DECLARE
  CUSTID VARCHAR2(9);
  POLICYNAME VARCHAR2(50);
  CHALLENGEID VARCHAR2(50);
  PINPOSITIONS VARCHAR2(20);
  O_RESULT NUMBER;
  O_CODE NUMBER;
BEGIN
  CUSTID :='400800500' ;
  POLICYNAME := 'POLICY';
  CHALLENGEID := 'CHALLENGEID1';
  PINPOSITIONS := 'PINPOS';

  CHALLENGEUPDATE(
    CUSTID => CUSTID,
    POLICYNAME => POLICYNAME,
    CHALLENGEID => CHALLENGEID,
    PINPOSITIONS => PINPOSITIONS,
    O_RESULT => O_RESULT,
    O_CODE => O_CODE
  );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('O_RESULT = ' || O_RESULT);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('O_CODE = ' || O_CODE);
END;

Comment: You're not supplying O_C => O_C

Answer (score 2):

if you are using toad, try it this way:

```
var o_result integer;
var ocode integer;
var oc integer;
exec ChallengeUpdate  ('400800500', 'POLICY', 'CHALLENGEID1', 'PINPOS', :o_result, :ocode, :oc  );
print o_result;
print ocode ;
print oc;
```

Answer (score 0):

From the declaration:

```
procedure ChallengeUpdate  
(
 CustID        IN   SEC_CHALLENGE.CUSTOMERID%TYPE,
 PolicyName      IN   SEC_CHALLENGE.POLICY_NAME%TYPE,
 ChallengeId       IN   SEC_CHALLENGE.CHALLENGE_ID%TYPE,
 PinPositions       IN   SEC_CHALLENGE.PINPOSITIONS%TYPE,
 o_result          OUT INTEGER,
 o_code            OUT INTEGER,
 o_c               OUT INTEGER
) as
```

Your call to `CHALLENGEUPDATE` happens to miss an output variable for `o_c OUT INTEGER`. You may try the bellow:

```
 exec CHALLENGEUPDATE( 
  CUSTID => CUSTID
, POLICYNAME => POLICYNAME
, CHALLENGEID => CHALLENGEID
, PINPOSITIONS => PINPOSITIONS
, O_RESULT => O_RESULT
, O_CODE => O_CODE 
, O_C => O_C_tobedeclared);
```